# What is the smallest number $d$, not a power of $2$, such that the number of groups with order d is unknown?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Here

https://oeis.org/A000679

it can be seen that the number of groups of order $2^n$ is particularly high.

> Besides the powers of $2$, what is the smallest number $d$, such that the number of groups with order $d$ is unknown ?

I guess it is a number of the form $2^n\times 3$ or $2\times 3^n$.

Comment: What does "unknown" mean, exactly? Given any $d$, a computer can easily crunch out in finite time all the possible multiplication tables on a set with $d$ elements, check which ones are groups, and check all the possible isomorphisms to count all the isomorphism classes. It's probably a very long computation, but it's certainly doable...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It is probably the number for which the computational resources so far deployed have been insufficient to the task. And there will be orders of groups for which the computational resources of the universe are insufficient. It is a practical enough question. I think it is unknown how many groups there are of an order as small as 2048 - unless you know different - any guesses as to how large the number might be?

Comment: I don't know whether the number of groups of order $2250 = 2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^3$ is known, but that is the smallest number $d$ (not a power of $2$) for which Maple does not currently know the number of groups of order $d$.

Comment: $3072 = 3 \times 1024$ might be the smallest seriously difficult number.